# Can I make a Google Doc shared with me more accessible on my Android device?

Tags: google-drive

A friend of mine shared a Google document with me. If I use my Gmail app on my Android device to open the email that includes the link, I can see the document in the Google Drive app.

However, I can't seem to find any way to mark that document using the Google Drive app so that I can get back to it easily. Every time I want to view the document, I have to find the email in which my friend shared the link, and then click that link.

Is there no way I can bookmark or add that document so that it is available without me having to search for it? Ideally, I could leave it open in the Google Drive app so that when I reopened the app it would show me the document without me having to select it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was shared to your Google account, you should be able to find it in `Shared with me`:

[image]